# How to Read Multiple dimensional JavaScript Object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
var result2 = xmljs.xml2json(response.content);
console.log(result2);
```

In AngularJS now I want to get value of `IsError` from the following JavaScript object:

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "s:Envelope",
            "attributes": {
                "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            },
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "element",
                    "name": "s:Body",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "element",
                            "name": "ValidateLoginResponse",
                            "attributes": {
                                "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"
                            },
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "type": "element",
                                    "name": "ValidateLoginResult",
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "xmlns:a": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BeehiveHrms.MobileServices",
                                        "xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                    },
                                    "elements": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "element",
                                            "name": "a:ErrorMsg",
                                            "attributes": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text",
                                                    "text": "Please enter valid username and password."
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "element",
                                            "name": "a:IsError",
                                            "elements": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text",
                                                    "text": "true"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "element",
                                            "name": "a:IsActive",
                                            "elements": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "text",
                                                    "text": "false"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know under which elements it is located, you need a **recursive search** for your JSON. Pick your favourite approach and reach the children of children of all of your nodes until you find what you are searching for.

I assumed you are always looking for `"name"` property. Here is the demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.JSON = {
    "elements": [{
      "type": "element",
      "name": "s:Envelope",
      "attributes": {
        "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      },
      "elements": [{
        "type": "element",
        "name": "s:Body",
        "elements": [{
          "type": "element",
          "name": "ValidateLoginResponse",
          "attributes": {
            "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"
          },
          "elements": [{
            "type": "element",
            "name": "ValidateLoginResult",
            "attributes": {
              "xmlns:a": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BeehiveHrms.MobileServices",
              "xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            },
            "elements": [{
                "type": "element",
                "name": "a:ErrorMsg",
                "attributes": [{
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "Please enter valid username and password."
                }]
              },
              {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "a:IsError",
                "elements": [{
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "true"
                }]
              },
              {
                "type": "element",
                "name": "a:IsActive",
                "elements": [{
                  "type": "text",
                  "text": "false"
                }]
              }
            ]
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }


  // recursive function
  function findNode(elem, currentNode) {
    var i,
      currentChild,
      result;

    if (elem == currentNode["name"]) { // can be a dynamic key
      return currentNode;
    } else {
      if (currentNode["elements"]) { // can be a dynamic key
        for (i = 0; i < currentNode["elements"].length; i++) {
          currentChild = currentNode["elements"][i];

          result = findNode(elem, currentChild);

          if (result !== false) {
            return result; // found
          }
        }
      }
      return false; // not found
    }
  }


  $scope.find = function() {
    var res;
    res = findNode($scope.search, $scope.JSON);
    if (res) {
      $scope.found = angular.copy(res.elements[0]);
    } else {
      $scope.found = null;
    }
  }
  $scope.search = "a:IsError";
  $scope.find();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
    <button ng-click="find()">Find</button>

    <br>

    <code>{{search}} : {{found}}</code>

    <hr>

    <button ng-click="s=!s">{{s ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} JSON</button>
    <pre ng-show="s">{{JSON | json}}</pre>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in:

```
elements[0].elements[0].elements[0].elements[0].elements[1].elements[0].text
```

I hope it helps!